# Vector space dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm a bit confused about finding the dimensions of vectors spaces.

For example, the space $V=\{\mathbf0\}$ has dimension $1$ or $0$?

How do I find the dimension of a vector space?

If $V=span\{\mathbf e_1, \mathbf 0\}$, then $dimV=1$ or $2$?

Comment: $V=\{e_1,0 \}$ doesn't make sense. Maybe you meant $V=\text{span}\{e_1,0 \}$, which you would write  $V=\text{span}\{e_1\}$

Comment: By definition, the dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis of that vector space.  (The vectors in a basis must be nonzero vectors.)  Accordingly zero vector space has dimension zero.

As for $V = \{{\bf e}_{1}, {\bf 0}\}$, it is not a vector space at all.  It is just a set of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: (Definition) Dimension of a vector space is the number of linearly independent basis vectors it has.

Note: $\textbf0$ vector can be generated by $\textbf e_1$ by using the scale factor $0$ and thus $\textbf0$ vector doesn't contribute to the basis in the above definition in the hint.