# Must the unit vectors implied by a row vector be unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

Earlier, I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4621390/170148) if the basis vectors in a column vector must be unique, and we decided the answer is yes, because the basis vectors that the scalars in a column vector scale define a vector space. And vectors that define a vector space must be linearly independent.

So, how about row vectors?

If we have a row vector $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix}$, should I think of it as $a\hat{i} + b\hat{j} + c\hat{k}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are scalars and $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ are linearly independent, unique, basis vectors? Does a row vector define a space of any kind?

Or perhaps I should think of $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix}$ as a mere bunch of scalars $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Or maybe I should think of $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix}$ as $a\hat{i} + b\hat{i} + c\hat{i}$? If so, would $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix} = a\hat{i} + b\hat{i} + c\hat{i} = (a + b + c)\hat{i}$ be true?

Comment: I think I'm seeing [here][1] that the unit vectors implied by a row vector don't have to be linearly independent. So, a row vector implies a row vector space, all of the unit vectors implied by the row vector are in that space, but some aren't strictly necessary to define the space.

Yar?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#Basis_2

Comment: I have no idea what this means "basis vectors in a column vector".

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misconception about a vector containing or encoding certain basis vectors.

> we decided the answer is yes, because the basis vectors that the scalars in a column vector scale define a vector space

The scalars in a column vector don't scale any basis vectors in particular. If the basis vectors under consideration happen to be the standard basis vectors ((1,0), (0,1), etc), then the column vector can be interpreted as the coefficients of a linear combination of those basis vectors. Otherwise the scalars of a column vector don't correspond so simply with the basis vectors.

> So, how about row vectors?

The distinction between row and column vectors is mostly cosmetic. The orientation matters for matrix multiplication. Otherwise, vectors are just elements of a vector space, which is defined by a handful of properties, none of which specify that a vector shall be standing up or lying down.

> If we have a row vector $\begin{bmatrix}a,b,c\end{bmatrix}$, should I think of it as $a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$

No, unless you are sure you're using standard basis vectors.

> linearly independent, unique, basis vectors

Just so you're clear, there's no need to specify unique on top of linearly independent, and linearly independent on top of basis vectors.

> Does a row vector define a space of any kind?

A vector defines a space made of all linear combinations of itself (in other words it spans a line). Multiple vectors can define a bigger vector space. In fact, if they are linearly independent, then they could be basis vectors.

> Or perhaps I should think of $\begin{bmatrix}a,b,c\end{bmatrix}$ as a mere bunch of scalars a, b, and c?

Yes :). An ordered bunch, at least.

> Or maybe I should...

No.

Comment: "You're simply the best."
--Tina Turner

Comment: I'm starting to think [my original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621390/must-basis-vectors-in-a-column-vector-be-unique/4621475#4621475) should have been, "Must the dimensions of a vector space be unique?"

I'd ask that, but there's a grumpy Gus out there tonight who thinks these are all the same question.

Maybe I'll just ask and see what happens to me. :)

Comment: Ah, wait. [Here we go](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2145921/170148): dimension is the count of basis vectors.